# ExAdmin - Add input for nested data

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, exadmin

I'm trying to add more data to CRUD to my admin interface. My schema looks like this:

```
schema "tree" do
  field :name, :string
  field :metadata, :map
  field :created_at, Ecto.DateTime
  field :updated_at, Ecto.DateTime
end
```

and my form currently looks like this:

```
form framework_tree do
  inputs do
    input tree, :name
  end
  inputs "Metadata" do
    input tree, :metadata, schema: [icon: :string, index: :integer, title: :string]
  end
end
```

Metadata looks like this:

```
{   
    "metadata": {
        "index": 1,
        "info": {
            "text": "Some random text"
        },
        "icon": "icon_1",
        "data_points": [
            {
                "default": {
                    "name": "Default"
                }
            },
            {
                "other": {
                    "name": "Other"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so far I'm able to edit top-level metadata strings and integers. But I'd like to edit `info.text` as well as the array of `data_points`. Can I add these to the `schema` array in the form? Or is there another way to easily edit this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect usecase for the [`Ecto.Schema.embedded_schema/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embedded_schema/1):

```rb
defmodule Tree do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "tree" do
    field :name, :string
    embeds_one :metadata, Metadata
    field :created_at, Ecto.DateTime
    field :updated_at, Ecto.DateTime
  end
end

defmodule Metadata do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :index
    field :info
    field :icon
    embeds_many :datapoints, Datapoint
  end
end

defmodule Datapoint do
 ...
end
```